# Is storing 400,000 data in Core Data for subway route-finding unusual?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am trying to make a subway app which finds the shortest path from station to station.

I tried Dijkstra algorithm with several samples of heap to actually calculate the best route everytime the user selects starting station and ending station.

But I am wondering if it would be better to store all possible routes in Core Data, so the app doesn't have to calculate the best route each time, but rather fetch the best route information from Core Data

There are 624 stations. and 624 X 624 = 389,376 existing paths from any station to any station.

The piece of information for EACH possible route would hold something like:

```
- starting station : String
- end station : String
- stations in-between : String 
- total time it takes in seconds : Double
- number of transfers : Int
etc.
```

My main question is : **Assuming I already have 389,376 data, would it take too much disk memory if i'd stored all 400,00 some data in Core Data? or would it be just a trivial problem.**

I am trying to avoid using Dijkstra because it's taking quite a lot of time to take into account transfer time, transfer preference, etc.

Comment: Assuming `station : String` is the station name, it might be a good idea to  use ordered relations instead of concatenated names for "stations in-between". Should decrease db size a little and certainly speed it up. The rest depends on your resources really, you might let user download pre-calculated routes info from your server and/or re-calculate routes on device when the stations list is updated. Completely static  database doesn't seem to be so good as you want to support user preferences.

Comment: Thanks. never thought about ordered relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to store all this data, i recommend you to use SQLite instead of CoreData to properly manage you cashed data size. there is good wrapper for that purpose
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

You can estimate the size of your database as

```
- starting station : String (average size about 20 bytes - one byte per char)
- end station : String (average size about 20 bytes)
- stations in-between : String  (average size about 20 bytes)
- total time it takes in seconds : Double (8 bytes)
- number of transfers : Int (4 bytes)
```

total : 72 byte per row * 400 000 = 27,4 Mb

Comment: Why SQLite instead of Core Data given that Core Data uses SQLite?

Comment: here is link that answers your question http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/ios-data-storage-core-data-vs-sqlite/240168843?pgno=2

Comment: in short, core data generates a lot of context, and if you do not want to grab a lot of space you can use sqlite. Of course, you can work with core data, but it about 2 times bigger in terms of space

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. I have several apps that 1GB to 11GB each on disk. It would seem your usage would be under 1GB.

For reference check your iPhone Preferences -> General -> Manage Storage to get an idea of other app's storage usage.

Do consider that many users may have only 16GB iPhones.